# How Do I Take A Set Of Names And Compile Them Into A Set Of Names With Distinct Occurances?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I am learning SQL. I want to try and see if I can query a database

```
SELECT AnimalName 
FROM animals INNER JOIN 
     animal_components 
     ON animal_components.AnimalID = animals.AnimalID
```

Which returns me:

```
Dog
Dog
Dog
Dog
Cow
Cow
Cow
Bird
Bird
```

Now that I have this output, I want to create a table that has the name alongside the frequency of which it occurred. However, I've been stuck on this for a while and seem to not be approaching the problem clearly.

Dog | 4

Cow | 3

Bird | 2

Thanks in advance for any knowledge anyone provides.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 0):

You want aggregation :

```
SELECT AnimalName, COUNT(*)
FROM animals INNER JOIN 
     animal_components 
     ON animal_components.AnimalID = animals.AnimalID
GROUP BY AnimalName;
```